# DVD Burning Error

Tags: windows-7, optical-drive, dvd-burning

For some reason, I got a 4.7 GB DVD that would only hold 4.36 GB when formatted. I tried formatting it again and now it holds 113 MB. What's the deal? I tried to use Power2Go but it said that it was not a rewritable disk while it was! Then it said that there is no disc in the drive at all. Help!

Comment: Anybody at all?

Comment: Aw, come on. There's got to be an answer to this!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help you with your problem at large, (sorry) but I can explain that there is no inconsistency between 4.7GB and 4.36 GiB.

The apparent difference lies in the fact that we are dealing with different units of measure. One is the GigaByte,

```
  1GB = 1,000,000,000 Bytes
```

while the other one is the GibiByte,

```
  1 GiB = 1024 x 1024 x 1024 Bytes.
```

Thus

> ```
>             1,000,000,000
> ```
>
> 4.7 GB = 4.7 ------------------------------- GiB = 4.37 GiB
>
> ```
>          1024 x 1024 x 1024
> ```

That's all.

Comment: I'm a hundred percent sure it was gigabytes, not gibibytes.